# Multiple versions of app in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, phonegap-build, publish

I wanted to know if it is possible to submit multiple versions of the same app to the Google Play store.  I know that Google Play allows developers to submit multiple APK's to the target certain device configurations, but we would like to release a different name of the app to each of our clients.  Things that would be different in each app are the logos, app names, access to different types of information for each customer.  I wanted to know if this would violate the Google Play Store's submission guidelines (it is an app built using Adobe Phonegap build, each app package name would be the same), would it be subject to rejection? I know that there are multiple questions on this site similar to this, but they are older questions and I wanted to see if this is something that Google Play is offering.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> "each app package name would be the same"

AFAIK, that not possible, since package name is used as ID in play store.

Answer (score 2):

The package names must be different. Ideally, you would have unique security keys that signed the APKs as well. It prevents one app from accessing the private data of another app. Other than that, there's no policy or technical block stopping you from posting the same APK with different flavors.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said - the package name is used as the ID in the Play Store.

But the way around this is very simple - just use different package names!

You'll be making the same app with different branding anyway so you'll already have different code bases.

Copy your entire app folder.

Find the config.xml. It looks like this (from the docs): http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/#example

Change the id. If you have two apps you'd have:

```
com.phonegap.appname1 

com.phonegap.appname2
```

Upload each app to a different PhoneGap Build repository. This will create two different apps. Easy.

Comment: The application is built using adobe phonegap build so I am not sure if I can changed the package name.